# How to invoke WebApi only if IIS Website is running / not idle

Tags: powershell, asp.net-core, iis, asp.net-web-api

IIS Website stops the working process when there are no new requests for some time.

I would like to Invoke WebApi using a http call if the worker process is running.
I don't want to wake up sleeping bunny.

This will be part of my DevOps realease pipeline. Before I release a new version and shut own old I want to notify online users. Obviously, if the app is sleeping, there are no online users.

Comment: The IIS "idle shutdown" feature was not designed to support what you wanted itself, but if you really want to check if a site is idle, query its application pool and see if any running worker process is there. IIS has several APIs for you to consume, such as PowerShell and REST API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Get-IISAppPool`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/iisadministration/get-iisapppool) to check if the app pool has any worker processes:

```
if ((Get-IISAppPool DefaultAppPool).WorkerProcesses.Count -gt 0) {
    # do something
}
```

Change `DefaultAppPool` to the real name of your app pool.